# Center input element both horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I try to center the `<input>` element in the black `<div>` container, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
main {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
main input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3em;
}
footer {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <input type="text">
  </main>
  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy method is to set the position on the container to relative, then set the position on the input to absolute. Then just set the top/right/bottom/left of the input to zero, and margin to auto. No CSS3 transforms needed:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
header {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
}
main {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
}
main input {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3em;
  margin: auto;
}
footer {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}
```

```html
<header></header>
<main>
  <input type="text">
</main>

<footer></footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `position: relative` other than `position: absolute`, which is centering based on the entire screen other than the parent element. Note that this will make the top part of the input box in the center. You will need to move it up a little bit by half it's height.

```
...
main input {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  width: 60%;
  height: 3em;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `transform:translateY(-50%)` and give the `main` div `position:relative` . Make sure to also include the different vendor prefixes.

```css
html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  main {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
          position:relative;
  }
  main input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 3em;
          -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
          -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
          
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <input type="text">
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make main position: relative

and your input position :absolute

```css
  html,
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  header {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
  }
  main {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
          position: relative;
  }
  main input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 3em;
  }
  footer {
    background-color: #fafafa;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40%;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Layout Example</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <input type="text">
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
</body>

</html>
```